# Front-End Editor for Wordpress Metaboxes

Tags: wordpress, forms, meta

I am currently creating a frontend editor for wordpress using TDO Mini Forms and I was wondering if there is a way to post values from a frontend form to a custom Metabox? I am using the wpalchemy metabox code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one of these could be of assistance?
Tutorial on [editing post data](http://voodoopress.com/expanding-our-front-end-post-meta-boxes-with-dropdowns-radio-selection-and-checkboxes/) from front end.

[Front End Editor](http://wpcandy.com/broadcasts/the-sweet-plugin/day-5) allows editing the entire post.

Another [Front End Editing plugin.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-frontend/other_notes/)

If you're up for coding it yourself, here's the [wordpress function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/edit_post) you'll want to use.  Or just [editing meta data.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta)

Comment: Thanks, the Front End Editor and the Front End Editing plugin seem to be exactly what I need.